# Deleted post that is still available in a review queue

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, deleted-answers

I reviewed a post in the “Suggested edit” queue and got [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63139312/checking-weather-inputs-got-values) which was already deleted.

I still had the ability to review this post although it has been already deleted. This is waste of time of reviewers. The suggested edit should be removed from the review queue if the post doesn't exist any longer.

Comment: Asked before, but no real answers yet: [Why are we reviewing edits of deleted posts?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343281)

Comment: Got a link to the review? it wasn't an audit was it? nvm, here it is for those interested: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26804101

Comment: This is link to the review. I wanted to improve edit but option `Improve edit` wasn't available https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26804101

Comment: This isn't really a bug; deleted posts can be edited into shape before being undeleted.

Comment: Pending suggested edits on posts are supposed to be deleted when the post to which they are associated is deleted. If this, in fact, happened as you describe, then it is a bug. While authors and privileged users can edit a deleted post, no one should be able to *suggest* edits to such a post.